# Jest doesn't see window.location and throwing an error

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I'm writing the script for the browser.
There is no local environments to run it.
Imagine that you have the script and you paste it to the browser console.

I'm using jest to test this script, but jest doesn't see `window.location` and other browser properties. In matter of fact thats correct because there are no browser properties because it is only js script written in typescript.

How can I mock it, or tell to jest to treat this code as it is run in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

In your `jest.config.js`, you should set the `testEnvironment` to `jsdom`.

See [Jest's documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string) on this property.

- For Jest **<= 27**, you already have this environment preinstalled in your dependencies.
- For Jest **> 27**, [you have to install the `jest-environment-jsdom` package separately](https://jest-archive-august-2023.netlify.app/docs/28.x/upgrading-to-jest28#jsdom).

**Example:**

```js
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const config = {
  // ...
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  // ...
};

module.exports = config;
```